# matlab does not save variables on parallel batch job

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I was running (in a cluster) a batch job and in the end I was trying to save results using save(), but I had the following error:

ErrorMessage: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 1
                       terminated abnormally for the following reason:
                       Cannot create 'results.mat' because '/home/myusername/experiments' does not exist.

why is that happening? What is the correct way to save variables in a parallel job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SAVE` in the normal way during execution of a parallel job, but you also need to be aware of where you are running. If you are running using the MathWorks jobmanager on the cluster, then depending on the security level set on the jobmanager, you might not have access to the same set of directories as you normally would. More about that stuff here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/mdce/setting-job-manager-security.html